# Not getting crash details in hockey webportal (iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode7.3, hockeyapp

I have integrated hockey sdk in my ios app and upload the dSYM.zip into the hockeyapp webportal.

This is to get the crash reports from my application, but I could see the raw crash details not the class , method and exact crash reason in hockey webportal dashboard.
Please advise me if i am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you picked the wrong dSYM. At the bottom of your crash log, you should find a section "Binary Images:" with the first line like this:

```
0x1000 -   0x222fff +AppName armv7  <1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef> /var/mobile/Applications/ABCDEF01-1234-5678-9ABC-DEF012345678/AppName.app/AppName
```

Copy the UUID, format it as a GUID, then you can find the dSYM on your Mac with this call:

```
mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == 12345678-90AB-CDEF-1234-567890ABCDEF"
```

Once you found the right dSYM, zip it, and upload to HockeyApp, then after a few minutes your symbolicated log should appear.